# @Value works in class annotated with @Controller but not in @Component

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my spring boot project when I am trying to inject values using `@Value` annotation its giving inconsistent behavior. In my controller it's working fine but when I use it in my `@Component` class the field is null. I tried using `@PropertySource` annotation on my component class but it still didn't work. I am using spring boot 3.1.0 and Java 17. Please advise.

Sharing repository link of the project.
[Contact Management Project](https://github.com/Codemode128/contact-management)

In this project I am trying to read the `algorithm` property value from properties file in my `src/main/java/com/shivam/cms/utils/EncryptionUtil.java` but it fails. Same works in `ContactContoller.java` file

Comment: Using `@Value` in `@Component` annotated classes should work fine. Can you give a code example where it doesn't work?

Comment: Hello I have shared my code repository please check.

Comment: I was just trying to print the value in constructor , i have no need for constructor injection. It was still null when i wasnt using constructor injection, so that question doesn't answer my query.

Comment: I have done my part of stackoverflow search but could not resolve it.

Comment: @Shivam... Can you add the relevant code of the `EncryptionUtil` to your question? And can you also give an example of how you verify that the property is `null`?

Comment: Did you read the answer there? "As far I remember, the value injection occurs after the constructor call"

Comment: Well i tried it again now without constructor injection and it seems to work now, I was stuck on it since yesterday and it wasn't working. My apologies @Mar-Z you were right.  Thanks guys.